# Creating a Variable Using a Loop

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, substring

I'm writing a program that's supposed to replace all of the instances of a single letter with another letter. I have some restrictions on the code though, I'm only allowed to use the String methods .length, .substring, .indexOf, and .equals. I can concatenate things using + instead of .concat.

My problem right now is, when I'm printing my results to the program, the answer has to be contained in a variable. I was previously using this code before I realized this:

```
    if (userCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("replace all")) {
        System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
        String replace = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the new character");
        String replaceWith = keyboard.nextLine();

        int count = 0;

        System.out.print("The new string is: ");
        while (lastCharacter >= 0) {
            char nextCharacter = userString.charAt(count);
            count++;
            String nextCharacterString = nextCharacter + "";
            if (nextCharacterString.equals(replace)) {
                nextCharacterString += replaceWith;
            }
            System.out.print(nextCharacterString);

            lastCharacter--;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

As you can see, this prints each character to the console one by one, instead of as a variable that can be manipulated later. The code I'm using right now (it is nowhere near working) is:

```
    if (userCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("replace all")) {
        System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
        String replaceString = keyboard.nextLine();
        char replace = replaceString.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter the new character");
        String replaceWithString = keyboard.nextLine();
        char replaceWith = replaceWithString.charAt(0);
        String allLetters = "";
        int count = 0;
        int indexOfReplacement = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char nextCharacter = userString.charAt(count);
            count++;

            if (replace == nextCharacter) {
                indexOfReplacement = count;
                nextCharacter = replaceWith;
            }
        }
        String sub1 = userString.substring(0, indexOfReplacement);
        System.out.println(sub1);
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So what is your problem? If you just want to save to a variable instead of printing, just replace `System.out.print(...)` with `myVariable = myVariable + ...` with myVariable being a String

Comment: Where are `lastCharacter` and `userString` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small snippet I wrote up. I made some assumptions about the contents of variables to make it be able to run, but it works, replacing all instances of `replace` with `replaceWith`:

```
String your_string = ""; // Variable to copy the new string into
String userString = "this_string"; // String to do replacement on
int lastCharacter = userString.length() - 1; // Length of inputted string
String replace = "g"; // Thing to replace
String replaceWith = "d"; // Thing to replace with
int count = 0; // Index of character in string
while(lastCharacter >= 0) {
    char nextCharacter = userString.charAt(count);
    String nextCharacterString = nextCharacter + "";
    if (nextCharacterString.equals(replace)) {
        nextCharacterString = replaceWith; // I changed += to = because we want to replace, not add
    }
    System.out.print(nextCharacterString);
    your_string = your_string + nextCharacterString; // This is where we add the correct character to the string
    lastCharacter--;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an `arraylist`

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
while(lastCharacter >= 0)
              {
                  char nextCharacter = userString.charAt(count);
                  count ++;
                  String nextCharacterString = nextCharacter + "";
                  if (nextCharacterString.equals(replace))
                  {
                      nextCharacterString += replaceWith;  
                  }
                  System.out.print(nextCharacterString);
                  list.add(nextCharacterString);
                  lastCharacter --;
              }
```

so you can manipulate it later

Comment: Why add them to an ArrayList when we have an entire library devoted to strings?

Comment: Jake stated that he needs to manipulate the strings later. So adding them to the list would do that. There could be many solutions though